# How could I render a list of different custom elements using the component tag

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-component, nuxtjs3, heroicons

So, I am trying to build a memory game using Nuxt3. My plan is to use HeroIcons icons for the images, my idea is to have an array with 8, 10, etc random icon names and display them in a grid using:

```html
<component v-for="icon in icon" :is="icon" />
```

Where the "icons" array is a list with the **names** of the components.
I have installed [Nuxt hero Icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxt-hero-icons/solid) and the auto import works very well.

The issue is that when I use the component tag, the rendered HTML is a component with that name instead of the the actual auto-imported element.

[image: Code]

[image: HTML]

I am using:

- "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.10"
- "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.11",
- "@nuxt-hero-icons/outline": "^1.0.1",
- "@nuxt-hero-icons/solid": "^1.0.1",

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Not sure if the given module supports dynamic icons on the fly, but you could start by trying the following `<component :is="outline-annotation-icon" />` (semicolon in front of `is` was missing).

Comment: Have a look at `@iconify/vue`. It provides many iconsets, including heroicons, and you can use it like `<Icon icon="heroicons-outline:annotation" />` or with parameter `<Icon :icon="icon" />`. https://docs.iconify.design/icon-components/vue/

Comment: @some-user yep, even if it works it cannot support dynamic icons on the fly. This is the way to go overall: https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons

Comment: @kissu I was not using the semicolons on purpose, my intention is to use the name of the components in an array of strings, not an array of components. I'll take a look at iconify and unplugin-icons for the time being, thanks for the answers!

Comment: @Ken White Thanks for the edit, I'll take it into the account for the future

Comment: The `<component>` component is expecting an actual Vue component instance, there is no benefit into having it static as a string. Because you could mainly write it directly at that point without the need of an `:is` of any sort.

Comment: @kissu I didn't know I needed the actual component given that I could use it as `is="div"`. My plan was to use an array with the names of the components I wanted to use that is why I was using `:is="<name>"`. Thanks for the answers